# Formato de String con Hex en Python

Tags: python-3.x, string

llevo buscando y no encuentro como cambiar el formato de un string dentro de **Python**
Primero convierto un str en hex y lo almaceno en una variable de esta forma:

```
for x in range(0,len(sn)):
hex_sn      += str('%X' % (ord(sn[x])))
```

después esa variable hex_sn le voy extrayendo cierta información para almacenarla en otra:

```
a    += hex_sn[0:8]
```

Sin embargo a la hora de imprimir ***a*** esta queda toda pegada: **2EFD008001** y mi idea es que quede separada de 2 bytes **2E FD 00 80 01**
Me gustaría saber si tienen alguna forma en la que esto se pueda hacer?
Yo recuerdo que en C# era mas sencillo puesto que solo jugabas con el formato de la cada de caracteres, sin embargo en Python no lo eh encontrado.

Saludos.

Comment: `' '.join(f"{hex_sn[i]}{hex_sn[i+1]}" for i in range(0, len(hex_sn), 2))`

Comment: Disculpa la f en tu solución que función tiene ? Te agradezco

Comment: Al poner 'f' delante de un string lo conviertes en un *f-string*. Lo que haces es buscar *expresiones python* encerradas entre `{}`, las evalua y las reemplaza dentro del string. El resultado es un string formateado con los reemplazos.